# How to fix Vim's random selection behavior inside tags?

Tags: html, vim, indentation

I have this block of text:

```
<div>
<span>
not indented correctly
</span>
</div>
```

If I put my cursor in the middle and type <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> visual inside tag, inside tag, this is what gets selected, which **is correct**

[image]

However, if I have this markup:

```
<div>
    <span>
    not indented correctly
    </span>
    <span>
    not indented correctly
    </span>
</div>
```

and I put my cursor on either of the spans, then I type <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> (just one more `inside tag` selection than the last) then it selects this:

[image]

**Notice how the linebreak after the first div is selected** which is incorrect. Also, if this whole block is already indented, it will include the spaces on the line before the closing `</div>`.

My goal is to hand manipulate those specific lines. **How do I correctly select just the LINES inside that tag?**

I have also tried starting the command with linewise, capital <kbd>V</kbd>, but the <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> keystrokes reset it to regular selection mode.

I am aware of the auto-indent `=` command which I don't want to use here, because I might not want the output of what `=` does, and `=` is notoriously bad anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior as <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>(<kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>)* selects the content between the opening and the closing tag. So the newline following the opening tag is logically included.

However to solve your issue, I would use <kbd>V</kbd> and the [MatchIt](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) plugin.

Concrete example (cursor by the arrow):

```
<div>
    <span> <-
    not indented correctly
    </span>
    <span>
    not indented correctly
    </span>
</div>
```

Then: <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>

Comment: Should be a comment, also no faster than hand modifying selection of inside tag

Comment: Well it appears to not be the solution you expect. But it is a viable alternative. Anyway, I'm curious how you hand modify the selection?

Comment: press `o` in visual mode